# How to capture minimum value of range and cell to the left in same row

Tags: google-apps-script

**The Code**

```
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test')
const values = spreadsheet.getRange('O2:O8').getValues()
const CurrentLow = Math.min(...values)
Logger.log(CurrentLow)
```

**The Logic**

- find the minimum value in range O2:O8
- capture the value of the minimum AND the cell to the left in the same row
- splice together with another set of values into a new range P:S

**The Problem**

I'm trying to capture the minimum value in my defined range along with the cell value to the left of it but not the entire row. I tried using

`const CurrentLow = Math.min(...values).offset(0, -1)`

but I get an error. To my understanding using offsets requires an identifier of a current cell and I'm not sure that's happening with how I've put this together.

The end goal is to capture a max value in one range, a minimum value in another range and splice them together into a new range P:S

How do I rework this problem to get the cell to the left as well as the min/max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `I'm trying to capture the minimum value in my defined range along with the cell value to the left of it but not the entire row.`, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value of the left side cell of the minimum value of column "O" using Google Apps Script.

`Math.min` returns number. Unfortunately, the Class Range is not returned. By this, `const CurrentLow = Math.min(...values).offset(0, -1)` cannot be used. Please be careful about this.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
  const values = sheet.getRange('N2:O8').getValues();
  const checkValue = Math.min(...values.map(([, o]) => o));
  const res = values.reduce((ar, [n, o]) => {
    if (o == checkValue) {
      ar.push(n);
    }
    return ar;
  }, [])
  console.log(res);
}
```

- When you want to achieve this with the maximum value, please modify `const checkValue = Math.min(...values.map(([, o]) => o));` to `const checkValue = Math.max(...values.map(([, o]) => o));`. By this, the value of the left side of the maximum value of column "O" can be retrieved.

#### References:

- [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I want the values from both O and N columns on the same row. I modified what you suggested slightly to 

`
  const res = values.reduce((ar, [n, o]) => {
    if (o == checkValue) {
      ar.push(n, o);
    }
    return ar;
  }, [])
  console.log(res);
}`

 to get the output i was after. Is this the best way to go about the solution provided?

Comment: @Welchums Thank you for replying. In your situation, I couldn't understand the actual situation. So, in my answer, it supposes that the possibility that the same minimum values are existed. In this case of `const res = values.reduce((ar, [n, o]) => { if (o == checkValue) { ar.push(n, o); } return ar; }, []) console.log(res); }`, when `ar.push(n, o)` is modified to `ar.push([n, o])`, the result value is returned as a 2-dimensional array. If the minimum value is only one, you can retrieve it as `res[0]`. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function celltoleftofminino() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
  const vs = sh.getRange('N2:O8').getValues().sort((a,b)=> a[1]-b[1]);//sort ascending with column o
  console.log('n: %s o: %s',vs[0][0],vs[0][1])
}
```